# Why is this statement false?

Tags: probability-theory

If $P(A^C) = \alpha$ and $P(B^C)=\beta$ then $P(A \cup B) < 1 - \alpha - \beta$

It is false. I know that and I can visualize it but how can I show it statistically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(A^c) = \alpha \implies P(A) = 1-\alpha$

$P(B^c) = \beta \implies P(B) = 1-\beta$

$$\begin{align} P(A\cup B) & = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)\\ & = 1-\alpha + 1-\beta - P(A\cap B)\\ & = 2-\alpha -\beta -P(A\cap B) \\ &\geq 1-\alpha - \beta\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks. I see it now because $(1 - \alpha - \beta) + (1 - P(A \cap B)$ where  $0 \leq P(A \cap B) \leq 1$. Sorry. They were moving operations or something so I couldn't edit that mess lol

Comment: You're welcome, Stephan! Yes, I was inconvenienced too, by the lack of access to the site!